# Uninstallation of VMware Workstation Player from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-uninstall, vmware-player

Uninstallation of VMware Workstation Player from Ubuntu 16.04. The commands have been given which are required to answer the question

Comment: This would help anyone who is finding a specific answer for Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (one way could be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

Put the command:

```
sudo vmware-installer -u vmware-player
```

After some time a window will open and ask you to keep or not to keep the configuration files. Just select 'No' and then 'Next'
Your VMWare Player will finally get uninstalled.